# Proof that function is differentiable using definition

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Can somebody check, did I prove correct that function is differentiable using definition. I have two proofs.

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x):=x^2$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x):=0$ if $x$ is irrational. Show that $f$ is defferentiable at point $x=0$ and find $f'(0)$.

$\textbf{Proof 1}$.Let $x \in \mathbb Q$, then

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x=0$

Let $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, then

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}0=0$.

So we can conclude that $f$ is differentiable at point $x=0$, with $f'(0)=0$

$\textbf{Proof 2}$

Consider $\Bigg \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-0 \Bigg \rvert$=$\Bigg \lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} \Bigg \rvert \leq \Bigg \lvert \frac{x^2}{x} \Bigg \lvert =  \frac{\lvert x^2 \rvert}{\lvert x \rvert}= \lvert x \rvert$. Now we use $\delta-\epsilon$ definiton to prove it. Given $\epsilon>0$ take $\delta: =\epsilon$, if $\lvert x - 0 \rvert<\delta$ then $\Bigg \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} -0 \Bigg \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert < \delta=\epsilon$. So we can conclude that $f$ has a limit at point $x=0$ with $f'(0)=0$

Are the both proofs correct? Thank you for help!

Comment: First proof is wrong, second is right (though you should say explicitly that the inequality is for $x\neq 0$ (because you're dividing by $x$), so you should also write $0<|x-0|<\delta$). THe first is wrong, because you can't fix an $x\in\Bbb{Q}$, and then still take the limit $x\to 0$ (likewise, you can't fix $x\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ and still take the limit $x\to 0$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you! I understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof $2$ is correct, albeit missing precise explanation. The key point is that $|f(x)|\le x^2$ holds regardless of whether or not $x$ is rational.

Proof $1$ has the right spirit (!) but is incorrect since “if $x\in\Bbb Q$, $\lim_x$...” is meaningless. When you take a limit in $x$, $x$ *ranges freely* over any real numbers, rational or irrational, in a passage to $0$. The strategy of proof $2$ is accordingly much more appropriate.

Bonus: can you see why differentiability fails at the nonzero points?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think yes, because this function is discontinuous at every point $x \neq 0$. Am I right?

Comment: @mathguruu You are right, that is one way to prove it. You’ll see that the same tricks don’t work at the nonzero points. $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}(f(x+h)-f(x))$ cannot exist (or indeed, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist for $a\neq0$), but to prove the derivative failure precisely you should treat it by cases.

Comment: Can you explain please, what did you mean with your last sentence ( but to prove the derivative failure precisely you should treat it by cases ).  I mean, how to do it?

Comment: @mathguruu It is a simple casework, all I meant was you have to write something for $f(x)\in\Bbb Q$ and write something for $f(x)\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.